# C For loop weird behavior on Mac

Tags: c, macos, gcc

Simple code:

```
int i;
for (i = 100; i >= 0; i-=10)
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

Starts printing at 90 (compiled with gcc 4.2 on Mac OSX 10.6.8). In *"C Programming Language" by Ritchie & Kernigan*, I read that `i` will be incremented only after the body of the loop is executed. Here it seems to be incremented before the body of the loop is executed. What's up with that?

Comment: How have you established that?

Comment: GCC 4.2.1, OS X 10.7.2. The loop starts at 100, as it should be...

Comment: as is, it will print 100. Post your full program where this is occurring.

Comment: silly me, that was a mistake. In an actual program I was modifying the var and didn't spot it straight away. Sorry!

Comment: @ParijatKalia i=-10 will set i to -10. it will not decrement by 10

Comment: Are you using a pirated version of MacOSX? Those are known to undercount.

Comment: @KerrekSB ha-ha, very funny! As I mentioned in my comment, I was wrong, the loop does behave as it should. The error was in my program.